# Scikit Ridge's alpha parameter to ElasticNet's alpha parameter

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I use sklearn.linear_model.Ridge and the alpha parameter is the L2 penalty.

However I try to find the result again with the ElasticNet model.
Alpha is despicted as `alpha * l1_ratio * ||w||_1 + 0.5 * alpha * (1 - l1_ratio) * ||w||^2_2`

So `alpha_ridge` is equal `0.5*alpha_EL` when `l1_ratio=0`, no ? 
When I put these inputs into `Ridge` and `ElasticNet`, I don't get the same result.
Can you explain to me why please ?

Thanks